# Dynamic Menu using Tile in Struts2

Tags: menu, struts2, membership, tile

Hi I need to make a dynamic menu in my struts2 application, so there should be two different menus for members of website and guests, currently I am using Struts2 and tile to have a basic menu but I do not know how to change it for members when they are logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have few options here

1. Create two menu set and when user got logged in to the system set his/her role and based on the role can show the menu items.

other solution, which is more flexible elegant and more powerful is to use spring security.Spring security comes with role system and some set of tags based on which you can show and hide option based on the logged in user and role assigned to the user.

I will go with the second one as its more flexible and easy to enhance in future.

Comment: I am not familiar with spring and my understanding is combining spring with struts2 will mate the application complex and error-prone, am I right? anyway, do you have any sample or tutorial for either of methods?

Comment: well that will not create application complex as adding your own role based system will do that and making it more unmanageable with future growth.